# PHP, Javascript live clock: how to correctly display last time database was updated?

Tags: php, javascript, time

trying to show the time (live and counting) as when the database was last updated:

```
function show_clock(){
my_element = document.getElementById("js_clock")
var tt = new Date().getTime();
var my_date = new Date(<?php echo $latest_timestamp*1000; ?>);
var hours = my_date.getHours()
var minutes = my_date.getMinutes()
var seconds = my_date.getSeconds()
console.log(my_date);
console.log(hours);
console.log(minutes);
console.log(seconds);
var dn="PM"
if (hours<12)
        dn="AM"
if (hours>12)
        hours=hours-12
if (hours==0)
        hours=12
if (minutes<=9)
        minutes="0"+minutes
if (seconds<=9)
        seconds="0"+seconds
var ctime=hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+" "+dn
my_element.innerHTML="<b style='font-size:14;color:black;'>"+ctime+"</b>"
setTimeout("show_clock()",1000)
}
window.onload=show_clock
```

As for the php:

```
$result = $newsfeed_db->queryDB($query);
foreach($result as $timestamp)
{
$latest_timestamp = $timestamp["db_date"];
}
$time_of_update = date("m/d/Y h:i", $latest_timestamp);
$tslu = (time() - $latest_timestamp);
```

display:

```
<div class="display_last_update"><?php echo "Database Last Updated: " . $time_of_update; ?></div>
<div class="display_last_update"><?php echo "Time Since Last Update: " . date("H", $tslu)." hours and ".date("i", $tslu)." minutes"; ?></div>
<div id="js_clock"><?php echo "Live Time Since Last Update: "; ?></div>
```

My current output in the js console is

the date of when the database was last updated. It's being shown as:

*Wed Jun 26 2013 14:29:35 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)*

Followed by the hours minutes and seconds for that time.

Now these 4 logs are also repeating every one second (based on the setTimeout at 1000). So, I feel like I'm on the right track but not quite there yet.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What are you wanting? To show how long ago it updated? Or just when it was last updated?

Comment: Sorry I should've been clear about that. Say it was updated one hour, 10minutes, and 20 seconds ago. The 'clock' would be counting upward: "Updated, 1 hour, 10 minutes, and 20seconds ago" while the 20seconds would be going up..20, 21, 22, etc etc.

Comment: Can you not get the unix time stamp and then deduct the current time stamp from the number to get the current hour minute and second then you can manipulate that string to look like you want

Comment: That's this: `$tslu = (time() - $latest_timestamp);`

Answer (score 0):

Just found this:

It would be similar to this code:

```
$to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00");
$from_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:21:00");
echo round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2). " minute";
```

Comment: The issue here is not that, the issue is the javascript and getting a LIVE (ie, ticking) clock/time since last database update.

Comment: Best I can do is a picture: http://i.imgur.com/O0h80KQ.png The one in bold is the one that should be live.

Comment: What about a simple updating the value of the minutes by a simple getElementById('minutes').innerHTML(second);

Comment: Well, what I'm confused on is how is using .innerHTML going to update the time on the fly?

Comment: My theory would be to create an Ajax request to a php page get the Ajax response every 1 second and use JavaScript to output the difference using innerHTML you could even get the php to workout the difference and output the updated version with js

Answer (score 0):

```
function dhm(t) {
    var cd = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    ch = 60 * 60 * 1000,
    d = Math.floor( t / cd),
    h = '0' + Math.floor( (t - d * cd) / ch),
    m = '0' + Math.round( (t - d * cd - h * ch) / 60000);
    return ["Time Since Last Update: " + d + " days", h.substr(-2) + " hours", m.substr(-2) + " minutes"].join(' ');
    }
    var last_update = new Date(<?php echo $latest_timestamp*1000; ?>);
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
            var now = new Date();
            var t = now.getTime() - last_update.getTime();
            document.getElementById("js_clock").innerHTML = dhm(t);
    }, 1000);
```

This could be tidied up but working as intended.